# GNU Build Multiple Files at Once

Tags: gnu, gnu-make

I need to use GNU build system to compile many files at once. So far, I've only seen examples on how to compile one file at once. This is my favorite reference:

http://www.scs.stanford.edu/~reddy/links/gnu/tutorial.pdf

It says:

**‘Makefile.am’**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello

hello_SOURCES = hello.c
```

**‘configure.ac’**

```
AC_INIT([Hello Program],[1.0],

[Author Of The Program <aotp@zxcv.com>],

[hello])

AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR(config)

AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([dist-bzip2])

AC_PROG_CC

AC_PROG_INSTALL

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])

AC_OUTPUT
```

But what do I do if I want to make `hello.c` and `hello2.c` at the same time?

Comment: This isn't a make question exactly, but a GNU build tools question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build multiple targets by default in GNU make, you generate a "phony" target, a virtual target that depends on both of your results, e.g:

```
.PHONY: both
both: hello hello2
hello: hello.o
hello2: hello2.o
hello2.o: hello2.c
```

This will build both `hello` and `hello2` if you run `make` or `make both`.

[Reference](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Phony-Targets.html)

For automake, you just need to define both programs:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello hello2

hello_SOURCES = hello.c
hello2_SOURCES = hello2.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `make -j num` to compile *num* files at the same time. You can omit `num` and let make compile as much files at the same time as possible. Usually it does not make things faster any more if you compile more files at the same time than you have CPUs/cores in your system. Make sure that all dependencies are listed before using this.

Answer (score 0):

Even if using automake, it only generates the Makefile for you. You end up using the plain `make` command.

Add command line option `-j` when running `make`. It will instruct it to run as many build commands as it can in parallel. You can also specify the maximum number of concurrent builds yourself with `-j 4`. (Usual good value is nbrProcessors+1)